# MongoDB simplifying double $elemMatch query

Tags: mongodb

I am still a bit humble with mongo queries, is it possible, or - regarding performance - necessary, to put the following MongoDB query into a smarter form? Does the double use of $elemMatch affect performance?

Example for a db full of chicken-coops:

`{chickens: {$elemMatch: {recentlyDroppedEggs: {$elemMatch:{appearance:"red-blue-striped"}}}}}`

for finding all chicken coops that have a chicken (in its chickens-array) which recently dropped a red-blue-striped egg (into its recentlyDroppedEggs-array).

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: You should provide a document as an example to be clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't need `$elemMatch` for that.  You could just use:

```
{'chickens.recentlyDroppedEggs.appearance': 'red-blue-striped'}}}}
```

`$elemMatch` is typically only needed when you want to match *multiple* fields in an array element or apply multiple operators to a single field (e.g. `$lt` and `$gt`).

Comment: thank you, just tried it, works perfect! was caught in the misbelief of having to $elemMatch always when querying arrays.